# Html label in QGIS Atlas

Tags: qgis, labeling, html, atlas

My Atlas-layer ist "xblattschitt-fuer-rodung-f". In the column "FOTO1" is the name of the jgp. My source is in a network at "z:\01\P156. In the next step I insert a html-Label

```
<style>
* {margin: 0px; padding: 0px}
</style>
<img src="file:///z/01/P156/[% "FOTO1" %]"
style="width: auto; height: 100%; display: block; margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;" />
```

Without success

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct?

Comment: I am not sure how to write the correct path

Comment: Try with this path:

<img src="file:///z:/01/P156/[% "FOTO1" %]"

Comment: You missed the colon in "z:", see nagib's comment. Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this path:

`<img src="file:///z:/01/P156/[% "FOTO1" %]"`

You missed the colon in "z:"